# Black Screen Output in Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I created a simple Apple Watch app in Xcode 6.2 to show a label displaying just "HELLO". But when the watch app is run,the watch screen appears,but it is completely BLACK.
    How to recover from this ? What are the general procedures to be followed while running an Apple Watch application?

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
       [self.watchlbl setText:@"Hello"];
        [super awakeWithContext:context];
    }
```

Is anything wrong in this initialisation? I have also initialised the label in the storyboard.

Comment: What is your label textColor ?

Comment: WHITE - the screen colour is made black & the label is made white

Comment: The iphone simulator gets activated first and the iwatch screen is always still..black. Is anything wrong as the iphone simulator is getting activated ?

Comment: @AlenAlexander Did you find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, always make the call to `[super awakeWithContext:]` **before** everything else.

Second, you might put your code into the `willActivate` method:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    [self.watchlbl setText:@"Hello"];
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, make sure to use the right target in the XCode menu - the WatchKit App has to be started - like so:

[image: Xcode Menu]

Comment: Still the same black screen

Comment: The iphone simulator gets activated first and the iwatch screen is always still..black. Is anything wrong as the iphone simulator is getting activated ?

Comment: You need to choose the WatchKit App target - see my edited answer.

Comment: Dennis, if I click on a particular button on iWatch,then,is it possible to watch a video on iWatch that was supposed to play on iPhone ?

Comment: @AlenAlexander I'm not sure about this. I didn't find anything in the docs apart from animations using `WKInterfaceImage` with several images. I think you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I was selecting iPhone 6 (6.2) the Watch App would not start, switched to iPhone 6 (6.3) and it worked.